# Getting a value based on an another within a group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table with large amount of data and I need to get some information with only one query.

Content of `PROCESSDATA` table:

```
 PROCESSID | FIELDTIME                   | FIELDNAME | FIELDVALUE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 125869    | 10/08/15 10:43:47,139000000 | IDREQUEST | 1236968702
 125869    | 10/08/15 10:45:14,168000000 | state     | Corrected
 125869    | 10/08/15 10:43:10,698000000 | state     | Pending
 125869    | 10/08/15 10:45:15,193000000 | MsgReq    | correctly updated
```

I need to get this result:

```
125869  IDREQUEST 1236968702 state Corrected MsgReq  correctly updated
```

So I made this kind of query:

```
SELECT PROCESSID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FIELDNAME = 'IDREQUEST' THEN FIELDVALUE END) AS IDREQUEST
       MAX(CASE WHEN FIELDNAME = 'state' THEN FIELDVALUE END) AS state,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FIELDNAME = 'MsgReq' THEN FIELDVALUE END) AS MsgReq
FROM PROCESSDATA
WHERE FIELDNAME IN ('IDREQUEST', 'state', 'MsgReq')
GROUP BY PROCESSID, FIELDNAME;
```

But I don't get exactly what I want:

```
125869  IDREQUEST 1236968702 state Pending MsgReq  correctly updated
```

I need to get the `FIELDVALUE` of a `FIELDNAME` based on `FIELDTIME`. In this example `FIELDNAME = 'state'` has two values `'Pending'` and `'Corrected'`,
so I want to get `'Corrected'` because its `FIELDTIME` 10/08/15 10:45:14,168000000 > 10/08/15 10:43:10,698000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX( ... ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ... )` to get the maximum of a column based on the maximum of another column:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/473c3f/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE PROCESSDATA ( PROCESSID, FIELDTIME, FIELDNAME, FIELDVALUE ) AS
          SELECT 125869,  TO_TIMESTAMP( '10/08/15 10:43:47,139000000', 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF9' ), 'IDREQUEST', '1236968702' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 125869,  TO_TIMESTAMP( '10/08/15 10:45:14,168000000', 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF9' ), 'state',     'Corrected' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 125869,  TO_TIMESTAMP( '10/08/15 10:43:10,698000000', 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF9' ), 'state',     'Pending' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 125869,  TO_TIMESTAMP( '10/08/15 10:45:15,193000000', 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF9' ), 'MsgReq',    'correctly updated' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 125870,  TO_TIMESTAMP( '10/08/15 10:43:47,139000000', 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF9' ), 'IDREQUEST', '1236968702' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 125870,  TO_TIMESTAMP( '10/08/15 10:45:15,193000000', 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF9' ), 'MsgReq',    'correctly updated' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT PROCESSID,
       MAX( CASE FIELDNAME WHEN 'IDREQUEST' THEN FIELDVALUE END ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE FIELDNAME WHEN 'IDREQUEST' THEN FIELDTIME END DESC NULLS LAST ) AS IDREQUEST,
       MAX( CASE FIELDNAME WHEN 'state'     THEN FIELDVALUE END ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE FIELDNAME WHEN 'state'     THEN FIELDTIME END DESC NULLS LAST ) AS state,
       MAX( CASE FIELDNAME WHEN 'MsgReq'    THEN FIELDVALUE END ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE FIELDNAME WHEN 'MsgReq'    THEN FIELDTIME END DESC NULLS LAST ) AS MsgReq
FROM   PROCESSDATA
GROUP BY PROCESSID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/473c3f/1/0)**:

```
| PROCESSID |  IDREQUEST |     STATE |            MSGREQ |
|-----------|------------|-----------|-------------------|
|    125869 | 1236968702 | Corrected | correctly updated |
|    125870 | 1236968702 |    (null) | correctly updated |
```

Comment: If this has answered your question then you can accept the answer to mark the question as closed (and upvote any or all questions which you think provided a valuable answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.PROCESSID, t1.FIELDTIME,t1.FIELDNAME,t1.FIELDVALUE,
t1.STATE,t1.IDREQUEST from PROCESSDATA as t1
inner join
(
select PROCESSID, max(FIELDTIME) as FIELDTIME from PROCESSDATA 
where FIELDNAME IN ('IDREQUEST', 'state', 'MsgReq')
group by PROCESSID
) as t2 on t1.PROCESSID=t2.PROCESSID and t1.FIELDTIME=t2.FIELDTIME
where t1.FIELDNAME IN ('IDREQUEST', 'state', 'MsgReq')
```

Comment: With this query i get only result about fieldname = MsgReq,                                

the two other fieldnames are missing (state & IDREQUEST)

--   
I need to get for every FIELDNAME its last FIELDVALUE (based on FIELDTIME)

Comment: You can included that in the SELECT statement. See my edited reply

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote you a very fast and efficient query that gets the last 7 days of processdata. and it also handles if two records have the exact same milliseconds, it will grab just 1.

```
SELECT PD.PROCESSID,
    (SELECT MAX(PD1.FIELDVALUE) FROM PROCESSDATA PD1 WHERE PD.PROCESSID = PD1.PROCESSID AND PD1.FIELDNAME = 'IDREQUEST' AND PD1.FIELDTIME = (SELECT MAX(PD2.FIELDTIME) FROM PROCESSDATA PD2 WHERE PD.PROCESSID = PD2.PROCESSID AND PD2.FIELDNAME = 'IDREQUEST')) AS IDREQUEST,
    (SELECT MAX(PD3.FIELDVALUE) FROM PROCESSDATA PD3 WHERE PD.PROCESSID = PD3.PROCESSID AND PD3.FIELDNAME = 'state' AND PD3.FIELDTIME = (SELECT MAX(PD4.FIELDTIME) FROM PROCESSDATA PD4 WHERE PD.PROCESSID = PD4.PROCESSID AND PD4.FIELDNAME = 'state')) AS state,
    (SELECT MAX(PD5.FIELDVALUE) FROM PROCESSDATA PD5 WHERE PD.PROCESSID = PD5.PROCESSID AND PD5.FIELDNAME = 'MsgReq' AND PD5.FIELDTIME = (SELECT MAX(PD6.FIELDTIME) FROM PROCESSDATA PD6 WHERE PD.PROCESSID = PD6.PROCESSID AND PD6.FIELDNAME = 'MsgReq')) AS MsgReq
FROM PROCESSDATA PD
WHERE PD.PROCESSID IN
      (SELECT PD7.PROCESSID FROM PROCESSDATA PD7 WHERE PD7.FIELDTIME >= (GETDATE()-7))
```

Comment: Oracle does not support the `TOP 1` syntax.

Comment: This will get a duplicate row for each entry in the table (you need to use `DISTINCT`) and it will use 7 full table scans (one for each query/correlated subquery) [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09516/2)

Comment: the performance of the query is crucial for me as I have a large amount of data in this table.